# Intercepting transaction multiple times

Tags: spring, hibernate

How bad is it intercepting transaction multiple times?
For example one service method marked @Transactional calls another service method which also is marked with @Transactional annotation and so on? Which problems may it cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `propagation` attribute at the `@Transactional` annotation. It is responsible for setting the expected behavior when a (second) method with `@Transactional` is invoked.

- @See Java Doc: [Transactional.propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#propagation%28%29)
- @See Java Doc: [Propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html)

Comment: Thanks, understood. Second transaction will not be opened if @Transactional annotation is used just empty